# Is there a name for the family of graphs in which all maximal cliques are maximum?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Some examples of these graphs and their clique number

- Edgeless graph - 1
- Path graph - 2
- Peterson graph - 2
- Octahedral graph - 3
- Cluster graph formed by any amount of copies of **K<sub>n</sub>** - ***n***
- Any clique sum of the cluster graphs above if no edges are deleted - ***n***

Comment: By "all maximal cliques are maximum" you mean that all maximal clicks have the same cardinality?

Comment: If so, this condition is equivalent to the graph's clique complex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex) being pure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex#Definitions), in case that's useful. (So you could refer to them as "graphs with pure clique complex" if you wanted.)

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Thank you, that was useful! Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Alright, I've done it!

Comment: "Triangle-free graphs" are a special case, and you hear discussions of those a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[clique complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_complex)" of a graph is the abstract simplicial complex whose vertices are the graph's vertices and whose faces are the subsets of vertices that induce cliques. An abstract simplicial complex is "[pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex#Definitions)" if every facet (i.e., maximal face) has the same dimension. The dimension of a face of an abstract simplicial complex is just one less than its cardinality. So the graphs you are asking for are precisely the "graphs with pure clique complex."

Answer (score 2):

The *complements* of these graphs are called [well-covered graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-covered_graph): these are the graphs in which every maximal independent set has the same size.